# Eclipse on Mac OS X : Shortcuts are broken

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm pretty new to Eclipse because I'm starting to learn Java Programming. I'm having problem with the editor.

I'm running Eclipse on an iMac with a German keyboard. The keyboard shortcut for *"Redo"* action is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
When I use this shortcut, a tiny window in the right down corner pops up and asks if I want *"Inspect"* or *"Redo"*...

In the preferences, I have three different *"Inspect"*, (just one was with a shortcut, but it was something like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Anyway, I erased it to be sure.

Afterwards I tried again, but the same little window asks me for *Insect* or *Redo*. Now I don't know what to do.

I'm having the same problem with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (*"Run"* action). For "Run" there is another keyboard binding.

In Eclipse preferences, I could not find both commands that are on the same shortcuts. Or better I found them but they are separate.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Keyboard shortcuts preferences :

> Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys

and unbind or rebind whatever is giving you trouble.

In your case, go to `Inspect` and remove the binding for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

In some cases, removing the binding for a key command will remove all bindings for it so after you do so, check out `Redo` and make sure it is still tied to the command.

Comment: Well i also tried to that… but there are some Commands that i cant edit. The Guys from Eclipse Developement also told me meanwhile, that it is a bug. When it be solved is unclear for me, so im just sitting, waiting, wishing…… ;o)

Comment: @user1946986 Weird, I had the exact same problem and this solved it for me. I'm on Eclipse 4.2.2, might be worth upgrading if you are on an earlier version